# asp date query formatting

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

i want to make an asp query so that an event is shown when it's date is greater or equal.

here's the code so far, but it doesn't work.

```
<%
    strDateNow = date
    strDateEvent = "30.05.2011"
%>

<% if strDateEvent >= strDateNow then %>
HELLO
<% end if %>
```

thanks for any help,
alex

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is VBScript + Classic ASP rather than .net?

`strDateEvent` is a string so the `>=` is not comparing dates.
To compare against `strDateNow` which **is** a date despite its name, you need to convert `strDateEvent` to a date in order to compare:

```
If CDate(strDateEvent) >= strDateNow Then
```

If this fails with a type error then the format `"30.05.2011"` cannot be converted so use another; `"10/04/2011"` (ensuring dmy order is appropriate for your locale)

Comment: Another option is to use [DateSerial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28VS.85%29.aspx) to declare the date: `strDateEvent = DateSerial(2011, 5, 30)`